# problem powershell cant access to a network share

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I use PowerShell to check if any ports are open on my computers. I have eight Windows Server 2008 R2 machines and run the following script:

```
$localhost = get-content env:computername

foreach($port in get-content "\\computer1\txtfiles\ports.txt")
{

    foreach ($hostname in get-content "\\compiuter1\txtfiles\servers.txt")
    {
        try
        {
            $sock = new-object System.Net.Sockets.Socket -ArgumentList $([System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily]::InterNetwork),$([System.Net.Sockets.SocketType]::Stream),$([System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType]::Tcp)
            $sock.Connect($hostname,$Port)
            $output = $localhost+","+$hostname+","+$port+","+$sock.Connected
            $output
            $sock.Close()
        }
        catch {
            $output = $localhost+","+$hostname+","+$port+","+$sock.Connected
            $output
        }
    }
}
```

I run this script on the eight computers from computer1 using:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer1,computer2 -FilePath F:\scripts\port-test.ps1
```

On the first computer (computer1- the machine that I execute the script from) I get an output but on computer2 I get:

```
Cannot find path '\\computer1\txtfiles' because it does not exist.
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\computer1\txt
files:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLo
cationCommand
```

Why doesn't PowerShell see the network share? How can I fix it?

Comment: can you manually type in \\computer2\txtfiles in another computer's run box and reach it?

Comment: yes i can go to this share

Comment: My guess is that on each machine, the command is trying to run on both c1 & c2... and c2 doesn't know what c1 is... try modifying the script so that it runs in a loop... `foreach $PcName in @ComputerList { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PcName ... }`. Okay, that's just pseudo-code, but the idea is to only pass one computer name at a time to the command.

Comment: if i run from computer1:    invoke-command -computername cumputer2 ... i get the same error message

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that the cause of this is a failed Kerberos multi-hop.

I guess what happening here is that the computer2 cannot access computer1 because it tries to access the share of computer1 with no login (*Null* session) or the computer credentials of computer2 (*DOMAIN\Computer2$*). Since this login does not have any rights, reading the text file fails.

Computer1 `->` Script runs under your account `->` Your account is used to access Computer1 `->` Runs fine

Computer1 `->` Run Script on Computer2 `->` PowerShell connects to WinRM using your account `->` You have access rights, so WinRM accepts the call `->` PowerShell send the scripts to WinRM `->` WinRM starts the script under its account (Computer2$) `->` Computer1 sees an incoming request to \txtfiles from the account "Computer2$" `->` This account has no rights so the access is denied `->` Error

As a first shot, I would try to give the user *Everyone* read access to the share `\txtfiles`. If this doesn't help, try to pass your login with `-credential domain\YourName` to `Invoke-Command`.

I guess the root cause is Kerberos related since [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says WinRM is able to use delegation of user logins.